# Mountain like plot for data in Square matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data as a square matrix. I want to plot it like `meshgrid` in Matlab (mountains with color gradients). Also, if there is a big cliff, I want to label it. Something like shown below

[image]

The data I have is

```
            _92765  _222156 _384259 _384249 _384247 _384250
_92765  -1  3.4 4.85106 8.12927 8.462   9.12643
_222156 3.4 -1  1.50877 3.66383 3.58554 3.69655
_384259 4.85106 1.50877 -1  4.48433 4.51367 4.14421
_384249 8.12927 3.66383 4.48433 -1  0.288   0.252
_384247 8.462   3.58554 4.51367 0.288   -1  0.196
_384250 9.12643 3.69655 4.14421 0.252   0.196   -1
```

How can I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: What does mountains with color gradients mean? When I hear mountains and cliffs, I think of off-piste skiing - but I don't think that's what you want here. Maybe post an image of what the final result should look like? Or some sample data of what you are trying to plot?

Comment: -1 unclear question with no data and no example output

Comment: Maybe this would be of use to you? http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=RTOMO:meshgrid

Comment: @y02g0 - thanks for updating your question - someone will be able to steer you in the right direction with this info.

Comment: ok. have reversed down vote; however, it would be even better if data were presented in an more easily reproducible form using `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the wireframe() function in the lattice library?

Here is an example from the on-line help:

```
library(lattice)    
wireframe(volcano, shade = TRUE,
    aspect = c(61/87, 0.4),
    light.source = c(10,0,10))
```

[image]